# How do I rename files when included in a jar by ant's jar task?

Tags: ant, jar, mapper

I want to put a set of files that look like this into a jar:

```
yay/my.jar
boo/my.jar
foo/my.jar
bar/my.jar
```

In the process, I want all of them renamed as follows:

```
yay_my.jar
boo_my.jar
foo_my.jar
bar_my.jar
```

I was hoping to use a mapper to accomplish this, but the fileset elements I am using and the jar task don't seem to support it anywhere.

How do I apply a mapper when building a jar, or else how can I perform a transformation like this?  I want to avoid copying all the files to the directory structure I want and making duplicates all over the place, which is how our build system works now.

Answer (score 17):

You can use a `zipfileset` with a `fullpath` attribute to rename the filename in the jar:

```
<jar destfile="newjar.jar">
    <zipfileset dir="yay" includes="my.jar" fullpath="yay_my.jar"/>
    <zipfileset dir="boo" includes="my.jar" fullpath="boo_my.jar"/>
    <!-- etc. -->
</jar>
```

You can't use a mapper with this technique though, you'll have to list each jar file explicitly. If you can assume that every file is named `my.jar`, and they are all in an immediate child directory, you can use the `subant` target to glob them all up:

```
<target name="glom">
    <subant genericantfile="${ant.file}" target="update-jar">
        <dirset dir="." includes="*"/>
    </subant>
</target>

<target name="update-jar">
    <basename file="${basedir}" property="dirname"/>
    <property name="path" value="${dirname}_my.jar"/>
    <jar destfile="../newjar.jar" update="yes">
        <zipfileset dir="." includes="my.jar" fullpath="${path}"/>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Comment: +1 Nice easy way to rename a file during the jar task. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Update: you probably actually want the [copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) rather than move, but the [regexp mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) works the same for both copy and move.

The following regexp will copy all jars in the jars directory to jars_out, mapping [folder]/[file].jar to [folder]_[file].jar.

```
<copy todir="./jars_out">
  <fileset dir="jars"/>
  <mapper type="regexp" from="([^/\\]*)[/\\](.*)\.jar$$" to="\1_\2.jar"/>
</copy>
```

The regexp mapper needs an appropriate regexp implementation jar on the classpath to work. Various implementations are available:

- [java.util.regex package of JDK 1.4 or higher](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html)
- [jakarta-regexp](http://jakarta.apache.org/regexp/)
- [jakarta-oro](http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/)

Comment: That's great but doesn't accomplish my goal of building the jar without making extra copies of the files.  Move would avoid copies, but then the jars would be rebuilt each time I build instead of only if their source files have changed.

Comment: However, the mapper tag you built is awesome, and I'll be borrowing that instead of coming up with one of my own. :)  I hadn't gotten far enough to actually build the mapper I needed yet since I couldn't get any mapper at all to work with fileset and jar.

Comment: sorry I misread the question. I'll have a think about how to accomplish this, but I am being called to the pub right now

Comment: Your help was still great, Rich.  It was a long question, and I think you can be forgiven for missing part of it. :)  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to (or can't readily) list each file individually, one solution is to use the Zip task, which allows a nested `<mappedresources>` (Ant 1.8.0+). Once the Zip task completes, you can use the Jar task to add/update the manifest and/or add an index.

Suppose, for example, that in addition to wanting

```
yay_my.jar
boo_my.jar
foo_my.jar
bar_my.jar
```

in the output JAR, you also have a directory `stuff/`, containing some files and subdirectories. If you want the contents of `stuff/` included in the JAR, but you want `stuff/subdir/*` to be added as `other_subdir/*`, consider the following:

```
<zip destfile="newjar.jar">
    <zipfileset dir="yay" includes="my.jar" fullpath="yay_my.jar"/>
    <zipfileset dir="boo" includes="my.jar" fullpath="boo_my.jar"/>
    <!-- etc. -->

    <mappedresources>
        <fileset dir="stuff"/>
        <compositemapper>
            <globmapper from="subdir/*" to="other_subdir/*"/>
            <identitymapper/>
        </compositemapper>
    </mappedresources>
</zip>
<!-- Update the newly-created ZIP in-place to add a basic manifest -->
<jar destfile="newjar.jar" update="true"/>
```

I tested this build file and it works with Ant 1.8.2. However, if after changing it Ant begins throwing a `NullPointerException`, see [Bug 54026](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54026).